# How to display latitude and longitude on Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I pass data of longitude and latitude from one activity to another activity, and it is successful, but how can I after received this data Display it on Google Maps as a location so the user will be see location in google map not see the number of longitude and latitude.

Note I pass data by use `getExtra()` and `putExtra()`

If anyone know solution please help me

```
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Main3Activity.this, MapsActivity.class);

               intent.putExtra("Latitude", Latitude);
               intent.putExtra("Longitude", Longitude);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    Intent i = getIntent();
        final String Latitude=i.getStringExtra("Latitude");
        final String Longitude=i.getStringExtra("Longitude");
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

Comment: Attach your code

Comment: Still problem in Intent i = getIntent(); ('getDoubleExtra(java.lang.String, double)' in 'android.content.Intent' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.String)')

Comment: You have tried my attached code?

Comment: Latitude and Longitude are Double not String

Comment: You have tried my attached code : Yes I do it

Comment: Latitude and Longitude are Double not String : yes same your code Exactly

Comment: So what is the error?

Comment: Come to chat please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212611/discussion-between-mohammadmoeingolchin-and-marwan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
final Double Latitude=i.getStringExtra("Latitude");
        final Double Longitude=i.getStringExtra("Longitude");
```

to

```
final String Latitude=i.getDoubleExtra("Latitude");
        final String Longitude=i.getDoubleExtra("Longitude");
```

Change `LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);` to `LatLng sydney = new LatLng(Latitude, Longitude);`

Try this code:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
Double Latitude=0.0;
    Double Longitude=0.0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        Latitude=i.getDoubleExtra("Latitude",0.0);
    Longitude=i.getDoubleExtra("Longitude",0.0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(Latitude, Longitude);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

Comment: There are two problem in that Firstly in part one with (final String Latitude=i.get Double Extra) I get error as ( 'getDoubleExtra(java.lang.String, double)' in 'android.content.Intent' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.String)')
then in part number two (onMapReady) i get error as (Cannot resolve symbol 'Latitude')    Sorry but I am a new developer

Comment: Please can you look here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61458513/how-to-move-camera-and-marker-in-google-map-to-data-of-latitude-and-longitude-re