# How to move camera and marker in google map to data of Latitude and Longitude received by intent.putExtra Android

Tags: android

I have pass data of latitude and longitude  from (activtiy1 ) to(activtiy2 ) by `intent.putExtra`.
It works, but location is default location it view in marker and camera in sydney , and not according to data that I passes from the first activity to the second activity.

The first activity

```
public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView textView4;
Button button2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
        textView4 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        final String Latitude=i.getStringExtra("Latitude");
        final String Longitude=i.getStringExtra("Longitude");
        textView4.setText(textView4.getText() + Longitude+Longitude );


        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Main3Activity.this, MapsActivity.class);
               intent.putExtra("Latitude", Latitude);
               intent.putExtra("Longitude", Longitude);
               startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The second activity

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
   Double Latitude=0.0;
    Double Longitude=0.0;
TextView textView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        Latitude=i.getDoubleExtra("Latitude",0.0);
        Longitude=i.getDoubleExtra("Longitude",0.0);

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
      LatLng sydney = new LatLng(Latitude, Longitude);
       mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
       mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));

    }
}
```

example of the data I pass to clarify problem \

[image]

And example of problem

[image]

what is there problem ? anyone know the solution for it ?

Comment: In Main3Activity why do you use   Intent i = getIntent();
        final String Latitude=i.getStringExtra("Latitude");
        final String Longitude=i.getStringExtra("Longitude");

Comment: Do you give data from another activity?

Comment: yes I get data from RecyclerView by  (onItemClick(int position)) I send data from this activity to  Main3Activity  by  (onItemClick(int position)) on RecyclerView  and RecyclerView  it get data by Volley connection from my databases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change

```
        final String Latitude=i.getStringExtra("Latitude");
        final String Longitude=i.getStringExtra("Longitude");
```

to

```
Latitude=i.getDoubleExtra("Latitude",0.0);
        Longitude=i.getDoubleExtra("Longitude",0.0);
```

like in MapsActivity. Don't forget to initialize it. 
Everywhere you get Latitude and Longitude value, they should be in Double not String.

Comment: I got it. Thank you for clarifying the cause of the problem. Yes, I was passing data as String .thank you to helping me.

Comment: I f you have a time Visit this topic, you may know what is causing the problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61444067/volley-connection-get-all-data-in-one-time-with-use-where-conditional-sentence/61448175?noredirect=1#comment108711955_61448175